# Nginx php routing issue

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I'm an Nginx beginner, I'm found a frustrating situation.

I have a php app that worked just fine on localhost, but after I moved it to a VPS server routing is broken - all urls render the main page. My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.me;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Add additional types
    include mime.types;

    location /cockpit {
        try_files $uri  /cockpit/index.php?$args;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
        location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$args;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|\?|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#       fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
#       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param COCKPIT_URL_REWRITE On;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ .sqlite$ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8889;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;.
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /banki {
        alias /var/www/banki;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html last;
    }
}
```

and my php routing is

```
$app->get("/", function($params) use($app, $twig) {

    $collection  = cockpit('collections')->findOne('posts');
    $type_collection  = cockpit('collections')->find('Type');
    $template = $twig->load('index.twig');
    if ( $collection) {
        $posts = cockpit('collections')->find('posts');
    }
    return $template->render([
        'posts' => $posts,
        'types' => $type_collection,
    ]);
});

$app->bind("/:type", function($params) use($app, $twig) {

    $collection  = cockpit('collections')->findOne('posts');
    $type_collection  = cockpit('collections')->find('Type');
    $template = $twig->load('category.twig');
    if ( $collection) {
        $posts = cockpit('collections')->find('posts');
    }

    return $template->render([
        'type' => $params['type'],
        'posts' => $posts,
        'types' => $type_collection,
    ]);
});
```

I used Google to look at a lot of ideas, but none have worked for me.

I know that this is not an issue with app itself, because if I run apache2 at port 8080 and go to mysite.me:8080 app works as expected.

Moreover, /cockpit location works fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Enabling debug log in nginx is useful in such situations.

Comment: What I'm looking for in debug file?

Comment: debug output will show how requests are processed and matched against locations in your nginx configuration.